# Strategy to make pdf() in R use other devices

Tags: pdf, r, png

This is a multi-part question to SO folks before I engage more with core team.

**Summary: On OS X, pdfs should be created using quartz, not postscript. Files are smaller, anti-aliased better, OS fonts including opentype are readily available, encoding is less painful, overall I think it’s a better device. On other platforms, it would be reasonable to use cairo, again a more modern pdf-writing device.**

Consider the behavior of the png() device. Although it is allegedly slated to move out of x11.R, it handles c("cairo", "Xlib", "quartz") with a default (options("bitmapType")) set by zzz.R (quartz if capabilities("aqua"), cairo if available, Xlib otherwise). PDF needs to behave the same way, so that in Sweave (or babel or whatever) my pdf figures can be generated using the appropriate device.

My [Sweave png patch](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=14418) works because png() takes care of getting the device option. An earlier version of the patch ([which I still use](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/attachment.cgi?id=1137&action=edit)) flips the device in Sweave, but I was smacked down for this and I know it’s sort of the wrong the place to do it.

There’s some alias cairo_pdf() (also in x11.R) that probably should not be there, shouldn’t that be merged into a device-switching pdf() ?

One approach is to add option "pdfType", which in turn I think should probably be more general – there is already a default device, it’s just that pdf() ignores it! I’m especially wary of introducing new global options because they are more likely to be rejected by core.

Comment: ... What is your question?  This reads like a development planning session log.

Comment: it kind of is, sorry if that’s inappropriate. I'm really not sure where to start on it and how little/much is right to do.

Comment: There are some notes on writing drivers for new devices at http://developer.r-project.org/

Comment: the r-devel list seems a more appropriate place to discuss this. Otherwise rephrase your post so there's a clear question asked.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'd need to implement a device driver. Mostly it sounds like you want to alias pdf() so that it calls quartz() or cairo() as appropriate. The quartz() device already supports PDF output to a file (among others) on OS X.

For your own personal use (I doubt this would find its way into core) you could just alias pdf() to take the appropriate action on each of your platforms and bring it in as a package or in your Rprofile.

```
pdf.orig = pdf

pdf = function(...) {
    // Insert code here
}
```